# How do i check null pointer exception in DATE data type

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, talend

[image]We have Talend Data Integration tool which uses eclipse code while sending the info from source to target system.
Getting  error

```
Exception in component tMap_1

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.tJDBCInput_2Process(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:1937)
        at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.runJobInTOS(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:5086)
        at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.main(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:4885)

        at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.tJDBCInput_2Process(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:2098)
    at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.runJobInTOS(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:5355)
    at bigdata.copy_of_readsysproandsendmail_0_1.Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.main(Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail.java:5154)
Job Copy_of_ReadSysproAndSendMail ended at 23:16 03/10/2016. [exit code=0]
```

**Input :**

Date data type is source of null values in tmap component

```
DNDB date type(source) ---->row1.DNDB(output) is Date data type. both are nullable.
```

**We tried :**
But did not work for us.

To avoid null
 row1.DNDB==null?"null":row1.DNDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row1.DNDB==null?"null":row1.DNDB` can't work :  you are assigning to the output value either "null" (a string, with the double quotes) or row1.DNDB , which should be a date. You will have a cast exception in compilation.

You can try either :

```
Relational.ISNULL(row1.DNDB)?null:row1.DNDB
```

if you want a Date return type ; 
or

```
Relational.ISNULL(row1.DNDB)?"null":TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row1.DNDB)
```

if you want a String return type for both values.

Also check that your output column is marked as nullable (checkbox)

Comment: Thanks for reply .After trying  Both  the  syntax on machine. still it is complaining about Null exception.

Comment: Is it the only field in your mapping ? Can this error be linked to another field ? In tMap , you can try to uncheck "die on error" in the "tMap Settings" (upper left part of the tMap window) : then you will have a second output for the rejects.

Comment: When i tried  this uncheck 'Die on Error' then  job executed  with  less number of rows . original no of rows 687 but it isfetching  650 only.

Comment: But i want all the rows ..  the  job  should fetch  all 687 rows in output.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your tMap to see what's going on.

Comment: Please find  Attached is screenshot  of tMAP in Question  section.

Comment: - Are you sure this is related to the DNDB column ? It could be linked to others.
- Make sur that all the columns in "Out" output are marked as nullable
- You can add all those columns to the reject output, and direct the reject output to a tLogRow : it will help you see where it comes from.
- Are you sure the "var" part is working correctly ? if row2.L is NULL, it could generate a Null Pointer Exception as well.

Comment: I am sure row2.L is excel column and it has values  all not null. all columns are nullable both the side .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124894/discussion-between-corentin-and-vickps).